# exceptions in jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I create some form of exception for elements that are are inside containers affected by event.stopPropagation() e.g

```
<ul class="test">
<li><a href="#" class="test1"></a></li>
</ul>
<script type="test/javscript">
$(".test").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(".test1").click(function(e){
    some statements...
});
</script>
```

I would like .test1 to fire an event when clicked.

Comment: What do you mean by creating an exception? Can you describe what you need in a little more depth? Your handler for `.test1` is called before the handler for `.test`

Comment: well .test1 is working when I dont use e.stopPropagation() on .test, but when I add it to .test .test1 stops working. So my guess is that stopPropagation somehow affects all sub-elements? Pretty new to this.

Comment: No `stopPropagation` stops bubbling up the tree, hard to believe what you're saying, you should create a http://jsfiddle.net to show your problem. Here's proof that it does work http://jsfiddle.net/Sz7HM/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

events bubble up, [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) in your case would stop any parent elements of `<ul class="test">` with click handling.

however you may be interested in checking for if propagation was stopped, use [`event.isPropagationStopped`](http://api.jquery.com/event.isPropagationStopped/) in your event handling.

Comment: so that link should fire an event given the code I've written?